# AES encyption from JAVA to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, cryptojs, password-encryption

I am trying to encrypt the password by AES at frontend using JavaScript. Want to do the same thing as below in JAVA Language.

```
public static SecretKey getKeyFromPassword() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    SECURITY_KEY = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    SALT = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(new String(SECURITY_KEY).toCharArray(), SALT, 65536, 256);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
}

public static String encrypt(String input) throws
        NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKeyFromPassword(), generateIv());
    return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes()), Base64.DEFAULT);

}

public static String decrypt(String cipherText) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeySpecException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKeyFromPassword(), generateIv());
    byte[] decryptedValue64 = Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(decryptedValue64);
    return new String(plainText);
}

public static IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
    byte[] iv = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
}
```

This is the code I wrote so far.

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js');


const digest = 'sha256';
const key = bin2String(SECURITY_KEY);
const iv = bin2String(iv_array);


function Encrypt (text) {
  return crypto.AES.encrypt(text, crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    iv: crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
    mode: crypto.mode.CBC,
    padding: crypto.pad.Pkcs7
  }).toString()
}

console.log(Encrypt("password11"));


function bin2String(array) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(array[i], 10));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log("SECURITY_KEY: "+bin2String(SECURITY_KEY))
console.log("SALT: "+bin2String(SALT))
```

But the result does not match. I think thie problem is IvParameterSpec. Is there any idea about how I can make it right for this code, please? :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe a padding problem? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding

Comment: How do we know that the results differ? The main issue is the missing PBKDF2 key derivation in CryptoJs. Just a side note: in Java, you are converting the plaintext a binary form using "input.getBytes()" - always choose a char set for the conversion - especially when running a code on different platforms.